# How can I carry out this force summation? Control volume involved

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, fluid-dynamics

I have a stationary jet engine on a test stand, like shown in the next figure:

[image: Stationary Jet]

The *control volume* is indicated in the figure as a dashed rectangle, that has its left side far upstream of the engine, and its bottom side far from the floor on which it rests. We consider *no friction*.

We know that the summation of forces over a control volume surrounding a stationary system is given by:

$\sum \textbf{F} = \int_{cs} \rho \textbf{u}\left(\textbf{u} \dot{} \textbf{n}\right)dA $

Where:

- *cs* stands for Control Surface.
- $\rho$ is the density of the fluid.
- $\textbf{u}$ is the velocity vector of the fluid, be it entering or exiting the cs.

The problem here is finding the expression of $\sum \textbf{F}$. I know the solution, but I am unable to find a way to reach it on my own. The solution, as given by the book, is:

$\sum \textbf{F}=T+A_ep_a-A_ep_e$

Where:

- T is the reaction to thrust shown in the above figure.
- $A_e$ is the nozzle area indicated in the figure.
- $p_a$ is the ambient pressure of air.
- $p_e$ is the exiting flow pressure.

What puts me off from finding *that* specific solution:

- The product $A_ep_a$ and the reaction to thrust $T$ both go in opposite directions but have the same sign in the final expresion of $\sum \textbf{F}$. Same thing happens to the product $A_ep_e$
- I am not sure I can determine whether a force is "pushing" the Control Volume (that is, entering the CV) or "pulling" (exiting) it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

The hypothesis are (I think I didn't miss a single one):

- Inviscid and stationary flow.
- No fricton involved.
- Ambient pressure of air, $p_a$, doesn't appreciably change over surfaces, *except possibly* in the exhaust plane of the jet.
- The reaction to thrust, $T$, is considered to be a normal force.
- We do *not* care about any axis other than x, that is where the jet thrust exists.

Answer (score 1):

The full Euler equations (so assuming inviscid) are:

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \iiint \rho \vec{u} dV + \iint_{CS} \left[\rho \vec{u} \left(\vec{u}\cdot \hat{n}\right) + P \hat{n}\right] dA = 0 $$

or in differential form if you prefer:

$$ \frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t} + \vec{u}\cdot\nabla\vec{u} + \frac{1}{\rho} \nabla P = 0$$

So your force expression is missing a term.

Comment: Remember that the flow is stationary so the time derivative is zero.

Comment: @JoseLopez You don't need to remind me of that -- that wasn't the term that is missing from your expression for force. I was just providing you the full equations. You need to identify which terms matter for your case, you already know the time derivative doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @tpg2114 for your answer. But still cannot figure out, how can your answer help me with the force summation? Or are you saying the book is wrong? I forgot to say we are considering no friction. Is that the missing term?

Comment: @JoseLopez In your question, you wrote: $\sum \textbf{F} = \int_{cs} \rho \textbf{u}\left(\textbf{u} \dot{} \textbf{n}\right)dA$. That expression is incomplete. It is missing a term. Once you get the correct expression from what I provided you, it is just a matter of drawing your unit normals on your control surface and adding up the terms.

Comment: Remembering of course that the unit normals are positive when pointing outwards from the domain.

Comment: Give me more hints. What is that missing term about? Is it friction? Having difficulties trying to understand your answer because of the Einstein notation used.

Comment: @JoseLopez I put it in vector form, if that really does make it easier for you.

Comment: Thanks @tpg2114. What exactly is P in your expression and how does it relate to the problem? I hope I am not overwhelming you with so many questions but I am still learning.

Comment: @JoseLopez $P$ is the pressure. $\hat{n}$ is the outward-facing normal vector.

Comment: Firstly, I projected your differential equations onto the x-axis, since we are concerned only on those componentes of force (and momentum) parallel to the axis of the jet. Secondly, there is no pressure gradient in this problem: how can the ambient pressure change for the given control surface? Thanks.

Comment: Let's assume my equations are wrong, we will work on it later. The thing is that I don't know how to perform the summation of forces to get to the final expression: $\sum \textbf{F}=T+A_ep_a-A_ep_e$. How can you help me with that? I tried a hundred of different possible ways to do it but cannot reach it. I am still stuck at this point and can't go on with the lecture.